# Hide share option from Google doc

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I am uploading / creating file on Google Drive using .NET SDK for google drive api. Everything works fine and I can give permission to user as per my business logic like writer,reader,commenter or owner. But I want to hide the Share button from everybody except Owner as my business logic should decide which file should be shared with whom and when.

Here is the code for sharing the document:

```
try
{
 Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission permission = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission();
switch (role)
            {
                case GoogleRoles.WRITER:
                case GoogleRoles.READER:
                case GoogleRoles.OWNER:
                    {
                        permission.Role = role;
                        permission.Value = userEmail;
                        permission.Type = "user";
                        break;
                    }
                case GoogleRoles.COMMENTER:
                    {
                        permission.Role = GoogleRoles.READER;  //Need to assign role before we assign the additional role of commenter.
                        List<String> additionalRoles = new List<string>();
                        additionalRoles.Add(GoogleRoles.COMMENTER);
                        permission.AdditionalRoles = additionalRoles;
                        permission.Type = "user";
                        permission.Value = userEmail;
                        break;
                    }
            }

PermissionsResource.InsertRequest insertRequest = DriveService.Permissions.Insert(permission, fileId);
insertRequest.SendNotificationEmails = true;
insertRequest.Execute();
```

Where `DriveService` is an instance of service account. Any pointer would be a great help.

Comment: @DalmTo do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had raised this as an enhancement, and got the response too. So in Google drive API its not part of permission but these are properties of file itself, so we need to set he properties instead of permissions like:

```
File.LabelsData labels = new File.LabelsData();
labels.Restricted = true;
File body = new File();
body.Labels = labels;
body.WritersCanShare = false;
```

It has solved the issue of `Share` but download issue is not solved it by above changes.  More details about this can be found at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Drive API doesn't yet support the feature of disabling sharing or disabling downloading. Please file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Drive

Comment: Thanks Eric Koleda, I will add the request.

Comment: Added this as an enhancement : https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3943

Comment: @Eric Koleda, we are also facing this issue. How can we track the progress of this feature request?